# Communicate between Discord bot and Node server

Tags: node.js, server, discord, discord.js

I am developing a web app with a complementary Discord bot. Currently, because I use Node for both, they are in the same project and share the same database connection with Mongoose. I can access the bot in the routes of the web app by requiring it as a module but it's rather clunky.

Is there a way I can send information back and forth between the bot program and the web server? I would just need to be send data like `{ "action": "send_message", "text": "hello world", etc.}` back and forth, and they would be running on the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a [REST Api](https://restfulapi.net/) in your Node app and have your discord bot communicate through it. At a glance, the API might have a route:

```
POST /v1/messages
```

which accepts an HTTP body containing `{ "text": "hello world" }` etc.

There are many HTTP server modules for Node, [`express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) being the most popular. Happy coding!

Comment: That would work great for communicating from the bot to the web server but what about the other way around? My most common use case would be sending data from the web server to the bot.

Comment: Outside of having the bot setting up a separate web server to receive incoming HTTP connections (similar to the server), you could make the data available on separate routes on the web server and have the client constantly polling looking for changes