# How do I communicate through my discord bot and website (and get/store data in my discord bot)

Tags: discord, discord.js, github-pages

I'm trying to make a Discord bot where whenever you press/do something on the website, it **communicates with the bot**, and **sends data** to it. Does anyone have any suggustions? Here is some of the code I have for one of the pages on my GitHub hosted site:

```html
<html>
<!–- Website Stuff -–>
<button onclick="share()">Share</button>
<p id="sharedtext"></p>
<script>
function share() {
var projectID = prompt('Whats the project ID of your scratch project?')

<!-- Send data to bot -->

document.getElementById("sharedtext").innerHTML = "Project Shared.";
}
</script>
```

I use discord.js to make my discord bots. I also have a good understanding of JavaScript too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communicate between Discord bot and Node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031023/communicate-between-discord-bot-and-node-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mysql database that saves the data from the website and the bot sets an Interval for like every 5 seconds to check if there is new data and if there is that it does the required action. The HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="share()">Share</button>
    <p id="sharedtext"></p>
    <script>
    function share() {
        var projectID = prompt('Whats the project ID of your scratch project?');
        var path = 'Action page path here'; //Change this to the action page path
        if(projectID !== null){
           var Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
           Http.responseType = 'text';
           Http.onreadystatechange = function(){
             if(Http.readyState == 4 && Http.status == 200){
                 document.getElementById("sharedtext").innerHTML = Http.response;
             }
           }
           Http.open("POST", path, true);
           Http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
           Http.send(`projectID=${projectID}`);
        }
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The action page:

```
<?php
   $hostname = 'localhost';
   $username = 'root';
   $password = '';
   $dbname = 'db';
   $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
   if(!$conn){
       echo 'There was an error while connecting to the database!';
       exit();
   }

   if(isset($_POST['projectID'])){
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE projectid = ?");
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['projectID']);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->get_result();
      if($result->num_rows < 1){
          $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO yourTable (projectid) VALUES (?)");
          $stmt2->bind_param("s", $_POST['projectID']);
          $stmt2->execute();
          echo 'Project Shared.';
          exit();
      } else {
         echo 'The project ID has already been shared!';
         exit();
      }
   } else {
       echo 'Invalid method';
       exit();
   }
?>
```

The bot:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const client = new Discord.Client();

var conn = = mysql.createPool({
     connectionLimit : 50,
     host            : 'localhost',
     user            : 'root',
     password        : '',
     database        : 'db'
});

var diff, length, numb;
function checkNew(){
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY id ASC', function(err, results){
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        if(length === results.length) return;
        diff = results.length - length;
        numb = results.length;
        length = results.length;
        while(diff > 0){
            results[numb - 1].projectid //Do something with the project id
            --numb;
            --diff;
        }
    });
}
client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Started`);
    setInterval(checkNew, 5000);
});
```

The MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable(
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    projectid TINYTEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry for being a total **nub** but I wanted to know what am I supposed to do with the MySQL file? Im thinking of just putting it into the same folder as the others. if im wrong, just tell me.

Comment: Also, I use [this](https://repl.it) to make my bot, and its saying this: 

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='

Comment: I can't see your repl file when I click on the link, so I can't see what the problem is. For the SQL you'll need a MySQL database what repl.it doesn't provide. You can look for another webhost that provides a MySQL database. At some discord bot hostings they also provide MySQL databases what you also could use for your website.

Comment: Here, just go to [This](https://replit.com/@newtristanchann/ScratchMIT).